# Trigger postgres update table mysql

Tags: mysql, postgresql, triggers

i have a system made with MySQL DB and Other system made with PostgreSQL. I want to create an trigger in postgres that insert rows in MySQL, but i don't know how do this, is it posible?

The reason is that i need to syncronize the users of both databases without knowing when the user is created.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use [mysql_fdw](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mysql_fdw) for that.

But I think that it would be a seriously bad idea to do that — if the MySQL database goes down, the trigger will throw an error, and the transaction is undone. Basically, you cannot modify the table any more. Moreover, the latency of the PostgreSQL-MySQL round trip would be added to each transaction.

I think you would be better of with some sort of log table in PostgreSQL where you store the changes. An asynchronous worker can read the changes and apply them on MySQL.

One more thought: You are not considering replicating database users, right? Because you cannot have triggers on system tables.

Comment: no, the users tables are very diferent, but the client wont change his system code to get the users from my database. The "solution" was that an trigger do insert in his database the username. Yes it's rare. Sorry for my bad english.